# Limits with more than 1 variable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For $\lim \limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{x+y+z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ are the following correct?

$\lim \limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{x+y+z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ for $x=y$ and $x=z$
$\lim \limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{x+y+z}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \lim \limits_{x\to0}\frac{3x}{3x^2} = \lim \limits_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\nexists \Rightarrow\lim \limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{x+y+z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\nexists$

Also how can I solve the following lim $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4+y^4}$

Comment: Did you try spherical coordinates

Comment: You solution for the first limit looks correct.

Comment: For the last limit, you could use $x^4+y^4 \ge 2x^2y^2$ and switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: @StackTD still cannot solve it, never used polar coordinates before for solving limits

Comment: What a horrible notation: "$=\not\exists$" -- this notation should $\not\exists$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on StackTD's hint:

$$0\le (x^2-y^2)^2 = x^4+y^4 -2x^2y^2$$ so $$x^4+y^4 \ge 2x^2y^2\\2(x^4+y^4) \ge x^4+y^4 + 2x^2y^2 = (x^2 + y^2)^2$$ and $$\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4 + y^4} \le  \frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}}{(x^2 + y^2)^2/2} = \frac{2e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4}$$ where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. By the definition of multivariate convergence, $$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4}$$